# Migrations do not follow timestamp order

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-migrations

I am working with Laravel 5.4 trying to run my migrations. I have read that the order of execution follows the timestamps of the migration files. But this is not the case, as I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint 
(SQL: alter table `aplicantes` add constraint `aplicantes_pais_id 
_foreign` foreign key (`pais_id`) references `pais` (`id`))
```

These are my migrations files:

```
2014_01_01_100004_create_pais_table.php
2014_01_01_100005_create_departamentos_table.php
2014_01_01_100006_create_aplicantes_table.php
```

And this is where migration complains:

```
class CreateAplicantesTable extends Migration 
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('aplicantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->unsignedInteger('pais_id');
            $table->foreign('pais_id')->references('id')->on('pais');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

This is my Pais migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I inspect the database, only the `aplicantes` table is created, which is the third in the order. I guess that is why the migration fails because the `aplicantes` table is being created first, which references a table that does not exist yet.

**EDIT**:

I have updated my migrations, creating an individual file for the foreign keys of every table. I'm getting an error when migrate:refresh, an access violation while dropping a foreign key, and I presume it's because of the same reason: migration is performing in alphabetical order, not by the timestamp.

**UPDATE**:

I had to rename every migrations file and now it seems working. Seems that migrate only care about days field in the naming convention of the migration files, not the seconds, as I was working with. 
Despite that I see a correct order of migrate in migrations table, it complains of dropping foreign keys when I have my migration file like this:

```
class AddAplicantesForeignKey extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('aplicantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('pais_id')->references('id')->on('pais')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('aplicantes', function(Blueprint $table)
    {           
        $table->dropForeign('pais_id'); 
    });
}
```

}

I manage to disable the complains by turn off the foreign key constraints check in my migration create table:

```
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('aplicantes');
}
```

I am not happy with this solution, but it seems to only be working this way.

Comment: How did you create your migrations?

Comment: php artisan make:model tablename -m;    
php artisan migrate

Comment: Check your migrations table.

Comment: now it is weirder, migrations table in MySQL says that is was executed as it should, in timestamp order. Why is it complaining about foreign keys?

Comment: show your pais migration

Comment: Can you try to run `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: @Giovanni I included in the question.

Comment: @utdev I am running refresh every time

Comment: this should be working... maybe your migrations table got messed up at some point. maybe drop the database and try from scractch

Comment: I haven't tried dropping migrations table, but I did delete all the row and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload` before running `php artisan migrate:refresh`?

Comment: Done, but it's the same.